# Permalink settings not saving

Tags: permalinks

I just started a new WP installation and my permalink settings are not saving. I have chosen the 'Month and name' option (`/2014/06/sample-post/`), but when I create a new post, the text shows up as `/2014/06/sample-post/`, but the link goes to the default `?p=x`. When I go to `/2014/06/sample-post/` with the correct information for the post, I get a not found error. `?p=x` works and shows the post.

The changes appear to save successfully ('Permalink structure updated.') although the `.htaccess` does not change - is it supposed to?

Is there anywhere that the setting is stored that I can manually change?

This is my `.htaccess` file:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Thanks in advance for any help!

Matt

Comment: Is this a multisite install? Flushing permalinks doesn't fix your issue? You've cleared/flushed all object caches? You're using Apache? Or are you using Nginx? Is the site in the root or a subfolder/subdomain? Have you or any of your plugins/themes added custom rewrite rules? Does this issue go away if you deactivate plugins and use only the standard default theme? More information is needed

Comment: Not a multisite install. There is another installation in a subdirectory. How would I flush permalinks and object caches? Apache, yes. The installation is in the root. I don't think they have, not to .htaccess at least. I deactivated all plugins and the issue re-occured. I have not tried resetting the theme yet. Will I lose theme options if I re-select the default theme? Thank you for your interest.

Comment: object caches depends on the plugins you're using the the object cache you're using, if you're using one. Your host should be asked as that's host/software/plugin specific. You shouldn't loose theme options but I cannot guarantee this without a full copy of your theme, take a backup just encase

Comment: Thank you for your interest, but I have found that there are [lots of people with issues using postname in wordpress permalinks](http://bit.ly/1jyZvUY) and so I have given up. Thanks again :)

Comment: The first result in the google search linked to suggests it's a server issue with mod_rewrite not being enabled. Also people not knowing how to fix it is not a valid reason to not try, plenty of people fail to fight cancer, that's more not less reason to figure out why

Comment: I understand that, it's just that I see lots of jumbled ideas/ways to solve it and in my opinion, it isn't worth trying all those ideas when they might not work. Thank you for your interest @TomJNowell